# it seems `ping` utility displays wrong information

Tags: ping

who knows what happened with `ping` utility?

```
ping eugen.tools.rf.net
PING eugen.tools.rf.net (208.91.197.27) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 208.91.197.27: icmp_seq=1 ttl=235 time=45.6 ms
64 bytes from 208.91.197.27: icmp_seq=2 ttl=235 time=55.4 ms
64 bytes from 208.91.197.27: icmp_seq=3 ttl=235 time=47.4 ms
64 bytes from 208.91.197.27: icmp_seq=4 ttl=235 time=71.5 ms
^C64 bytes from 208.91.197.27: icmp_seq=5 ttl=235 time=51.2 ms

--- eugen.tools.rf.net ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 13315ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 45.634/54.198/71.461/9.259 ms
```

Here it shows me that ping is ~50ms, but it tooks around 5-7seconds to display that information. Also you can see that overall it takes 13315ms,but averages seems does not take it into account.

My OS: Linux Mint v21.1 Cinnamon

```
$ uname -a
Linux kes-X406UA 5.15.0-73-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 15 15:18:26 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I tried on two different computers with same OS on same network:

At point (1) there were delay. I suppose packet loss occur. We can see on (2) that there is more much time passed then packets sent. There should be difference at transmitted/received, but it was not shown.

[image]

If I ping with `-n` option I do not see the stuck and difference in transmitted VS time.

Comment: Which OS? What are you system details? Do you get the same or similar behavior on a different system on the same network? Can you test the same system on a different network?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to indicate what operating system you are running, as it does not match, the output of ping on either Windows 10 or Windows 11

Answer (score 3):

The 5-7 seconds is how long it took for the failed attempt to resolve 208.91.197.27 back to a domain name (i.e. to perform a reverse-DNS lookup).

Reverse DNS for 208.91.197.27 (i.e. PTR records on `27.197.91.208.in-addr.arpa`) is delegated to a pair of `ns*.confluence-networks.com` nameservers, none of which respond to any DNS query. The result is a ~5 second timeout.

Use `ping -n` to disable rDNS lookups. Use Wireshark/tcpdump to see whether a program might be trying to do something on the network (e.g. to see 'ping' sending DNS queries in this case). Use `dig -x 208.91.197.27` to attempt a rDNS query yourself (it'll fail with SERVFAIL after a few seconds, meaning no servers answer). Use `` dnstracer -s. `arpaname 208.91.197.27` `` to quickly find the delegations (these are done through ARIN, apparently).

Comment: I extended info.